# How to get the value back from a view which have been update for the quantity field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, view

I am trying to understand how to get the new value from the view.
First time I am coming in the screen the quantity is 1.  I update the quantity to 2.

When I am performing an `int nbrCart = cart.GetCount();` I still have 1. I guess it is because the cart has not been updated and still contains the initial value of 1.

The question is how can I get the new value added from the user from the Index?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartItems[ix].Quantity
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartItems[ix].Quantity, 
                new  {style = "width:30px; text-align:right;",
                onkeyup = "clearUpdateMessage();",
                onchange = "clearUpdateMessage();"
                })
```

**CartController.cs**

```
       public ActionResult UpdateCartCount(int id, int cartCount)
    {
        ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel results = null;
        try 
        { 
             // Get the cart 
             var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            // Get the name of the product to display confirmation 
             string productName = dbProduct.Carts
                 .Single(item => item.CartId == id).Product.Description;

             int nbrCart = cart.GetCount();   <=== the number is 1  and it should be 2
                                                   since I update the quantity to 2

              // Update the cart count 
             int itemCount = cart.UpdateCartCount(id, cartCount);
```

Index.cshtml

```
  @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

  @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
   }

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  { 
  <h3>
      <em>Visualisation </em> du panier:

      @if (TempData["err_message"] != null)
      {
          @TempData["err_message"]
      }

  </h3>

  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $('.RemoveLink').click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                  url: '@Url.Action("RemoveFromCart","Panier")',
                  data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
                  type: 'POST',
                  cache: false,
                  success: function (result) {
                      $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).remove();
                      $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                      $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + result.CartCount + ')');
                      $('#update-message').text(result.Message);
                      $('#cart-total').text(result.CartTotal);
                      $.get('@Url.Action("CartSummary", "Panier")');
                      $('#content').html(result);
                  },
                  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                   }
              });
              return false;
          });
      });

      $(function () {
          $(".RefreshQuantity").click(function () {
              // Get the id from the link 
              var recordToUpdate = $(this).attr("data-id");

              var countToUpdate = 0;
              if ($("#" + $(this).attr("id")).val() !== '') {
                  countToUpdate = $("#" + $(this).attr("id")).val();
              }
              if (recordToUpdate != '') {        
                  // Perform the ajax post 
                  $.post("/Panier/UpdateCartCount", { "id": recordToUpdate, "cartCount": 
                           countToUpdate },
                      function (data) {
                          // Successful requests get here 
                          // Update the page elements                        
                          if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                              $('#row-' + data. DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                          }
                          $('#update-message').text(htmlDecode(data.Message));
                          $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                          $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                          //Only process the callback data when no server error occurs
                          if (data.ItemCount != -1) {
                              $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                              $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                          }
                      }
                  );
              }
          });
      });

      $(function () {
          if (typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
              String.prototype.trim = function () {
                  return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
              }
          }
      });

      function clearUpdateMessage() {
          // Reset update-message area
          $('#update-message').text('');
      }

      function htmlDecode(value) {
          if (value) {
              return $('<div />').html(value).text();
          }
          else {
              return '';
          }
      }
  </script>



  <div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CartItems.Count; i++)
    { 
     <p>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CartItems[i].Quantite)
     </p> 
    }
    </div>

   <div id="update-message">

   </div>

   <div id="content">
      @if (Model.CartTotal != 0)
      {
         <p class="button">
            @Html.ActionLink("Paiement >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
         </p>
         <p class="NouvelAjout">
            @Html.ActionLink("Ajouter un autre article >>", "Magasin", "Home")
         </p>
      }

   <table>
     <tr>
         <th>
             Produit
         </th>
         <th>
             Prix (unitaire)
         </th>
         <th>
             Quantite
         </th>
         <th></th>
     </tr>

     @{int ix = 0;}

     @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
     {
         <tr id="row-@item.ProduitId">
             <td>
                 @Html.ActionLink(item.Produit.Description, "Details", "Produit", new { id = 
                      item.ProduitId }, null)
             </td>
             <td>
                 @item.Produit.Prix
             </td>
             <td>
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartItems[ix].Quantite, 
                     new  {style = "width:30px; text-align:right;",
                     onkeyup = "clearUpdateMessage();",
                     onchange = "clearUpdateMessage();"
                }) 
             </td>
             <td>
                 <a href="#" class="RefreshQuantity" data-id="@item.PanierId"
                    id="CartItems_@(ix)__Count">Refresh quantity</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;  />a
             </td>
             <td>
                 <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.PanierId"> Enlever du panier      
                      >> </a>
             </td>
         </tr>
         ix++;
     }

     <tr>
         <td>
             Total
         </td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td id="cart-total">
             @Model.CartTotal
         </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </div>

 }
```

PanierController.cs

```
         [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateCartCount(int id, int cartCount)
    {
        ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel results = null;
        try 
        { 
             // Get the cart 
             var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            // Get the name of the product to display confirmation 
             string productName = dbProduit.Paniers
                 .Single(item => item.PanierId == id).Produit.Description;

             int nbrPanier = cart.GetCount();

              // Update the cart count 
             int itemCount = cart.UpdateCartCount(id, cartCount);

             //Prepare messages
             string msg = "La quantité de " + Server.HtmlEncode(productName) +
                          " a été ajusté dans le panier.";
             if (itemCount == 0) msg = Server.HtmlEncode(productName) +
                      " a été enlevé de votre panier.";
             //
             // Display the confirmation message 
             results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
             {
                 Message = msg,
                 CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                 CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                 ItemCount = itemCount,
                 DeleteId = id
             };
        }
        catch 
        {
            results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message = "Error occurred or invalid input...",
                CartTotal = -1,
                CartCount = -1,
                ItemCount = -1,
                DeleteId = id
            };
        }
        return Json(results);
    }
```

Comment: In `public ActionResult UpdateCartCount(int id, int cartCount)` what is the return type? `View()` or `PartialView()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thing Like this.

Through `Jquery async call` you can do like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#Quantity').blur(function () { //Quantity Textbox Blur event or update button click event you can use
              $.post('@Url.Action("UpdateCartCount")', { 'id': 'User Id Here', 'cartCount': this.value  }, function (data) { // Post the updated value to your controller - Action Result
                  $('#DivQuantity').html(data); // Refreshing Quantity 
              });
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I added the full index.cshtml

Comment: Is is working? Can u post the `ActionResult` Method fully (that is what i asked earlier comment)?

Comment: still not working I am trying to compare your Jquery with the one I have to see what can be wrong.  I put the PanierController.cs  thanks for your help

Comment: in the <a href="#" class="RefreshQuantity" data-id=@item.PanierId"  I change this txt-id="CartItems_@(ix)_Count"  to id ="CartItems_@(ix)_Count"  since txt-id was giving me an error unknown attribute 'txt-id'

Comment: You are welcome. :) Just try removing "-" Like `txtid`. And what is that error? +1 for your try.,

Comment: txtid same errror unknow attribute 'txtid'  Will it cause a problem if I put id instead and changed all the txt-id to only id ?

Comment: check the index.cshtml  I put the full code and look for RefreshQuantity which is the jquery code I am trying to debug

Comment: I changed the txt-id for id since I was getting an error.  witch variable should be here for the id ?

Comment: Ok I want to align these two text "Mettre a jour la quantite" and "Enlever du panier"   now they are on a separate line which is fine but I will like to get them under each one.

Comment: Yeah ok. But if my answer is helpful make it as answered (accept it) to help the community standards.

Comment: try to add the </br> tag between the html.

Comment: it comes out on separate line but not under the other.  it comes out on the next line but at the end of the first line it changes line and appear there.   I will like it will be align with the first line